# Code not working onchange event after change of select option

Tags: jquery

The following script is firing for the first time but is not working onchange of five select dropdowns. Please guide why the code is not working after first time and if this code can be optimised.

```
<script>
             $(document).ready(function(){  
                $('#cfy1').change(function() {
                        var selectedOption = $('#cfy1 option:selected');
                        $('#show_finyear').html(selectedOption.val());
                });
                $('#cmd2').change(function() {
                        var selectedOption = $('#cmd2 option:selected');
                        $('#show_commandName').html(selectedOption.val());
                });
                $('#Stn3').change(function() {
                        var selectedOption = $('#Stn3 option:selected');
                        $('#show_stationName').html(selectedOption.val());
                });
                $('#status4').change(function() {
                        var selectedOption = $('#status4 option:selected');
                        $('#show_statusList').html(selectedOption.val());
                });
                $('#cfa5').change(function() {
                        var selectedOption = $('#cfa5 option:selected');
                        $('#show_cfaList').html(selectedOption.val());
                });
                var finyear     = $("#show_finyear").html();
                var cmdname     = $("#show_commandName").html();
                var stnname     = $("#show_stationName").html();
                var statusname  = $("#show_statusList").html();
                var cfaname     = $("#show_cfaList").html();
                $.ajax({  
                        url:"get_value.php",  
                        method:"POST",  
                        data:{finyear:finyear,cmdname:cmdname,stnname:stnname,statusname:statusname,cfaname:cfaname},  
                        success:function(data){  
                             $('#recordsfromraky').html(data);
                        }  
                });

            });  

        </script>
```

Please don't vote negative. There are many who would be able to use these types of bits. Thank you.

Comment: Was the ajax call meant to be triggered evrytime a value changes (in any of the selects) ?

Comment: Yes sir. All these values are sent to get_value.php where MySQL statement is run with these values in WHERE Clause and the table is updated with fresh records. Actually, thats what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: The ajax request is being made on page load only...before any values get set by user

Comment: Yes sir, Correct. But what is preventing it to be executed every time there is a change in one of the five dropdowns ?

Comment: Because you aren't including it in any of the change event handlers. Wrap the ajax code in a function and call that function inside those change handlers

Comment: I tried doing like this but it is giving under unregonised token do_ajax()   `$('#cfa5').change(function() {
      var selectedOption = $('#cfa5 option:selected');
      $('#show_cfaList').html(selectedOption.val());
      function do_ajax();
    });
    $(function do_ajax() {
     $.ajax({  
       url:"get_value.php",  
       method:"POST",  
       data:{finyear:finyear,cmdname:cmdname,stnname:stnname,statusname:statusname,cfaname:cfaname},  
       success:function(data){  
         $('#recordsfromraky').html(data);
       }  
     });
    });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the guidance and assistance of dev8080

```
<script>

            $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('#cfy1').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#cfy1 option:selected');
                    $('#show_finyear').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });
            $('#cmd2').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#cmd2 option:selected');
                    $('#show_commandName').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });
            $('#Stn3').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#Stn3 option:selected');
                    $('#show_stationName').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });
            $('#status4').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#status4 option:selected');
                    $('#show_statusList').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });
            $('#cfa5').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#cfa5 option:selected');
                    $('#show_cfaList').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });

        });  
        fetchChange();
        function fetchChange() {
                var finyear = $("#show_finyear").html();
                var cmdname = $("#show_commandName").html();
                var stnname = $("#show_stationName").html();
                var statusname  = $("#show_statusList").html();
                var cfaname     = $("#show_cfaList").html();
                window.alert('yep');
                $.ajax({  
                        url:"get_value.php",  
                        method:"POST",  
                        data:{finyear:finyear,cmdname:cmdname,stnname:stnname,statusname:statusname,cfaname:cfaname},  
                        success:function(data){  
                             $('#recordsfromraky').html(data);
                        }  
                });
            };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have understood the concept- you need a call to ajax in ***each*** of your handlers.

Just in case -

```
    <script>
         var fetchChange = function(){
                var finyear     = $("#show_finyear").html();
                var cmdname     = $("#show_commandName").html();
                var stnname     = $("#show_stationName").html();
                var statusname  = $("#show_statusList").html();
                var cfaname     = $("#show_cfaList").html();
                $.ajax({  
                        url:"get_value.php",  
                        method:"POST",  
                        data:{finyear:finyear,cmdname:cmdname,stnname:stnname,statusname:statusname,cfaname:cfaname},  
                        success:function(data){  
                             $('#recordsfromraky').html(data);
                        }  
                });
            };

            $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('#cfy1').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#cfy1 option:selected');
                    $('#show_finyear').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });
            $('#cmd2').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#cmd2 option:selected');
                    $('#show_commandName').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });
            $('#Stn3').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#Stn3 option:selected');
                    $('#show_stationName').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });
            $('#status4').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#status4 option:selected');
                    $('#show_statusList').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });
            $('#cfa5').change(function() {
                    var selectedOption = $('#cfa5 option:selected');
                    $('#show_cfaList').html(selectedOption.val());
                    fetchChange();
            });

        });  

    </script>
```

I would also suggest disabling the selects temporarily while an ajax call is being made.